# Is there a way to assign value to a ctypes variable in general python convention?

Tags: python, ctypes

I've defined a ctypes variable:

```
abc=ctypes.c_double.from_buffer(struct, STRUCT.field_1.offset)
```

`abc` represents field_1 of a ctypes structure instance `struct` with class definition `STRUCT`. Later, if I want to modify the value of `abc`, I have to do like this:

```
abc.value=1.0
```

which will also change the value of `struct.field_1` as I expect.

Upon modifying the value of `abc`, however, I could have no idea what the datatype of `abc` is, so simply using conventional syntax

```
abc=1.0
```

will redefine `abc` as a normal python variable and `struct.field_1` will not change accordingly. How can I change value of `struct.feild_1` through `abc` using conventional python syntax?

Comment: Normally you would use `struct.field_1 = 1.0`, assuming `field_1` is a `c_double`. You can get and set simple C types (and also `c_char` and `c_wchar` arrays) directly as attributes of a struct or union, without using the `value` attribute. To avoid this behavior requires using a subclass such as `class my_double(c_double): pass`.

Comment: As far as your general question goes, there's no way to hook assignment to do something special for a particular name. That would imply typed names/variables, which is simply not part of the Python language. Objects have a type, but names are just tags that reference an object.

Comment: As a side note, I would avoid  using ctypes at all -- because you aren't referencing the real header file you are asking for all sorts of low-level memory access bugs. It's much nicer to use tools like Cython (or cffi or swig).

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible -- in Python, the behavior of names (or 'variables') isn't configurable, only the behavior of objects (or 'values'). Plain old `foo =` rebinds a name, it doesn't rely on any object behavior to do so.

You might find http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html elucidating.